# Module: Show Category blog Fulltext in Module

Tags: module, menu

Related Q/A: **[How to create a category blog layout with all articles shown in full?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10374/how-to-create-a-category-blog-layout-with-all-articles-shown-in-full)**

I have the same issue as the referenced article above. I want a category blog to show introtext and readme by default, but on certain menu items I would like only the fulltext to appear.

The suggested solution by FFrewin works: create a new category type called **blogfull**.

*Unfortunately* I need a similar solution as a module. 
My website home page has a half dozen modules sprinkled across user4-user7. The modules are of type article newsflash. Like category blog, I see no way to choose fulltext only.

So it looks like I need a new module type called say **newsflashfull**.
But I've looked around and had no idea what moving parts need cloning/changing.

Help?
Using joomla 3.7.5

Comment: I could suggest you look for other content modules that likely would offer the features you want. Test the available core article modules, if there is any that can come close to your requirements, or check in JED for articles modules (free or paid). https://extensions.joomla.org/category/news-display/articles-display/

Comment: I have a series of show, about 6 per year.

Comment: On the home page are two Newsflash modules. On Now, and Coming Soon
There is a shows menu that lists shows by year, plus On Now and Coming Soon.
The shows have IntroText of a small image and a short blurb
and a FullText of a large image and a long blurb.
On the Shows menu, the category blog shows IntroText for all shows, except on now, where full text is shown.
On the home page the Coming Soon module shows IntroText; the On Now should show Full text.

Comment: I'd like to move the articles just by changing their category from Coming Soon, to On Now, To 2017 history.
I see no options in any module that allows me to choose FullText only. If I select don't show IntroText, it shows nothing.
Is there some combination of options that can accomplish this behaviour that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
I found the code for referencing the articles in a category here : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239605/how-to-get-article-from-the-specific-category-joomla)

So I created a custom module for the On Now shows (category 79):

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
->where($db->quoteName('catid') . ' = 79 and ' . $db->quoteName('state') . ' = 1 and ' . $db->quoteName('featured') . ' = 1');
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
echo $row->fulltext , '<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a template override of `/modules/mod_articles_news/_item.php` and add `echo $item->fulltext;`. If you want entire article text to be shown as if it didn't have read more, append fulltext to introtext: `echo $item->introtext . $item->fulltext;`.